# trouble converting data from string vector to floats and doubles

Tags: c++

I'm new to c++ and I'm writing a program that takes in a huge list of data of multiple types (some int, some float, some double, and some string.  What I did was read in all the data to a single string vector and Now I'm trying to sort all the data into structures.  This is where I'm running into a problem.  I can't seem to convert the data in the string vectors to their correct type to be placed in a structure.  I've tried using the `stof` and `stod` functions but get error: 'stof' was not declared in this scope and error: 'stod' was not declared in this scope.  So Now I'm trying to use stringstreams to convert but I keep getting an infinite loop error and I have no idea why.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Station
{
    string StationID, StationName;
    float Elevation;
    double Latitude, Longitude;
    int Date, MXPN, MaxTemp, MinTemp, ObsTime;
};

int main ()
{
    vector <string> Data;
    string DummyLine, TempLine;
    int Size = 0;

    ifstream InputFile;
    InputFile.open("finalc++.csv");
    getline(InputFile, DummyLine);
    while (InputFile.good())
    {
        getline(InputFile, TempLine);

        stringstream ss (TempLine);
        while (getline(ss, DummyLine, ',')) {
            Data.push_back(DummyLine);
        }
        Size++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= Size; i++)
    {
        Station Entry[i];
        Entry[i].StationID = Data[(i * 10)];
        Entry[i].StationName = Data[(i*10) + 1];
        float TempFloat;
        stringstream FloatStream;
        FloatStream << Data[(i*10) + 2];
        FloatStream >> TempFloat;
        Entry[i].Elevation = TempFloat;
        //Entry[i].Latitude = stod(Data[((i*10) + 3)]);
        //Entry[i].Longitude = Data[((i*10) + 4)];
        //Entry[i].Date = Data[((i*10) + 5)];
        //Entry[i].MXPN = Data[((i*10) + 6)];
        //Entry[i].MaxTemp = Data[((i*10) + 7)];
        //Entry[i].MinTemp = Data[((i*10) + 8)];
        //Entry[i].ObsTime = Data[((i*10) + 9)];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The stof and stod methods were introduced in C++11. Which C++ version are you compiling with?

Comment: @RetiredNinja same user asking both questions, did he have to update the previous question, or it's ok to ask in new one with new ideas??

Comment: Idk I'm using codeblocks but Have no idea what c++ version I'm using.  I believe it's the GNU GCC Compiler.  Sorry for the additional thread but I didn't know If I should just edit my original or not.